# Is it safe to use android sqlitedb in android.app.Service (concurrency, thread safety)

Tags: android, cordova, android-sqlite, cordova-plugins

I know that's quite common use case to use sqlite within android.app.Service. But is it safe?

What happens when there are multiple instances of same Service? They all will open and write to same db file. There is section about Sqlite
[concurrency](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). But what is the actual behaviour on Android? Anybody any real experience?

Is android version compiled with [SQLITE_THREADSAFE](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6).
There is no such a method sqlite3_threadsafe  in android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase

To give you some context. I'm developing https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation. It is basically background service which will be writing user locations to sqlite. But there can be multiple apps can use the plugin so there can be multiple instances of the background service. All of them writing to same sqlite db file. But not sure what will actually happen in this case. Will concurrent inserts fail?